# ngx-translate and *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, ngx-translate

I have this code

```
<div *ngFor="let service of services">
    <span><img  [src]="service.imgPath" alt="{{ service.name }}"/></span>
    <h4>{{ service.name}}</h4>
    <p>{{ service.desc }}</p>
</div>
```

How can I do translation of each service that have 3 parameters

In regular case I use `{{ 'something' | translate  }}` , where "something" is
placed in .json file

```
"something" : "translation"
```

So how can a use it in state of ngFor?
It read me an object from .json, but not array of objects that what I need in my case

Answer (score 4):

First of all you will need to import ngx-translate in app.component.ts:

```
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
....
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
   return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}
...
imports: [
    ...
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
          deps: [HttpClient]
        }
    })
]
...
```

Then you need to have under assets two files one f.i en.json for English and another one for Spanish for instance, es.json containing two objects. In en.json:

```
{
  "something":  "something translation in English"
}
```

In es.json:

```
{
  "something": "something translation in Spanish"
}
```

Then, in your component where you have the code you mention:

```
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
...
constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
        translate.setDefaultLang('en');
}
....
```

In the template:

```
<div *ngFor="let service of services">
   <span><img  [src]="service.imgPath" alt="{{ service.name }}"/></span>
   <h4>{{service.name | translate}}</h4>
   <p>{{service.desc}}</p>
</div>
```

Note that your services object must contain something as string so it will be feasible to be translated.

Answer (score 0):

```
use translate.get('jsonKey').subscribe( (response: any)=> {

services = response;


});
```

Note - //make sure your json structure is correct