# Is there a way to implement i18n on an Angular PipeDate

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I have an application that it's running in two language (I can change an choose the language I want bu using i18n) English / French.

At the moment i can get the date only in english even if I select the French Language.

```html
<div class="information">
  {{ information.date | information:'EEEE'}} {{information.date | date:'d'}} {{ information.date | date:'MMMM'}} {{ information.date |
  date:'yyyy'}}
</div>
```

This is my ts that allow me to change all the language of my application it will call `assets/english.json` where I stored my translation.

In my `app.component` I got this so I can get the language

```js
translate.setDefaultLang('en')
const browserLanguage = translate.getBrowserLang()
const language = localStorage.getItem('language')
if (language === 'fr' || language === 'en') {
  translate.use(language)
} else if (browserLanguage === 'fr' || browserLanguage === 'en') {
  translate.use(browserLanguage)
} else {
  translate.use('en')
}
```

Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: Do you know ngx-translate library? It makes very simple to implement i18n dynamically. Source: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core

Comment: @kboul i'm using it but don't know how to implement it here

Comment: Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44744818/ngx-translate-and-ngfor/50871365#50871365

Comment: @kboul i know how to do this but my question is about date it's not the same thing

Comment: I just saw that you use ngx-translate library. I am sorry, it was not mentioned.

Comment: It's okey, didn't find a way to implement an i18n in date, i have 2 language and i want as soon as i select exemple french, instead of Monday i'll get Lundi ...